# Magento Edit Email Order Confirmation Template NOT in the backend

Tags: php, magento, email, templates, zend-framework

i want to know, where the email-template file for the order-confirmation email is stored in magento. i want to edit the last 3 rows, with tax, shipping and total in it.

does anyone know where it is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are in `template/sales/order/totals.phtml`. But beware that this file is also used in "My Account" page.

Instead you should override it by adding a layout update to your layout files (fx local.xml in your theme):

```
<sales_email_order_items>
   <action method="setTemplate"><template>path/to/another/template.phtml</template></action>
</sales_email_order_items>
```

You can find the master template for different emails in `app/locale/country_code/email/sales/`

Comment: hey thanks for your fast answer. i found the file, but how can i add "Shipping" to the shipping price?

Comment: If you want to add totals, you don't need the template. Have a look at http://turnkeye.com/blog/magento-development-add-total-row-checkout/

But beware that Magento's totals sorting is buggy currently.

Comment: Temporary fix for sorting bug: Replace _compareTotals function in app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Config/Ordered.php with the version I uploaded here: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/9550247

Comment: thanks thats good, but i only want to edit the 3 excisting one, shipping tax and total

Comment: What exactly do you want to change?

Comment: For me its a german shop, so want it like this way, under the product table the first row should be `Zwischensumme`->`subtotal`, second row `Versandkosten`->`shippingcost`, third row `Summe`->`total`, last row `enthaltene MwSt. 19%`->`tax`

Comment: you should use csv translation for this

Answer (score 0):

1. Please login to admin panel
2. go to System --> Transactional Emails
3. Click on "Add new template".
4. Select "Template" and click on "Load Template".

Make changes in loaded html template and click on "Save Template".

Comment: sorry guy, thanks for your answer, but i want to edit without using the admin panel. see my title

Answer (score 0):

You can also set the theme as a module, add the template override in the config.xml and add the template in app/locale/en_US/template/email/themename

```
<config>
  <global>
    <template>
        <email>
            <sales_email_order_template translate="label" module="sales">
                <label>New Order</label>
                <file>themename/sales/order_new.html</file>
                <type>html</type>
            </sales_email_order_template>
        </email>
    </template>
  </global>
</config>
```